# Customize only one column admin template

Tags: python, django, admin

I have simple model like this

```
class Result(models.Model):
    detail = models.TextField(blank=True)
    in_file = models.TextField(blank=True)
    out_file = models.CharField(max_length=2000,blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Now I want to us `<audio>` tag in admin template

For the first try

```
class ResultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ["in_file","show_out_file","detail","pub_date"]

    def show_out_file(self,obj):
        return "<audio>test</audio>"
        #return "<audio>" +obj.out_file +"</audio>" ## it doesn't work though.
```

It shows `<audio>test</autio>` directly to the page, tag is parsed.

Next, I think I should override the admin template.

So I made this file `templates/admin/base_site.html` and edit.

It works, I can customize the main page of admin.

However how can I edit model(`Result`) admin page or only can I change only out_file column???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`format_html(...)`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) function to render the tags

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


class ResultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["in_file", "show_out_file", "detail", "pub_date"]

    def show_out_file(self, obj):
        audio_html = """
        <audio controls>
          <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
          <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
        """
        return format_html(audio_html)
```

Comment: Wooooo Its quite simpler and easier solution than I thought. thank you very much !!